# quarkus-redis-client - How to insert JSON?

Tags: redis, quarkus

How to insert JSON using quarkus-redis-client?

I tried writing the json as a String, but I don't know if it's correct.

```
@Singleton
public class EmployeeService {

    @Inject
    RedisClient redisClient;    

    public void insert(Employee employee) throws JsonProcessingException{
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String str = mapper.writeValueAsString(employee);
        redisClient.set(Arrays.asList("employee", str ));
    }

    Employee get(String key) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {

        ///Response res = redisClient.get(key);

        String str = redisClient.get(key).toString();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Employee emp = mapper.readValue(str, Employee.class);

        return emp;
    } 
    
}
```

source code: https://github.com/alissonmelonascimento/quarkus-app-redis

Answer (score 1):

Redis does not support JSON out of the box. It does only support the following [datatypes](https://redis.io/topics/data-types). So it is OK to store JSON as a string.

But if you really need JSON support, you can try installing [RedisJSON module](https://oss.redis.com/redisjson/) in your server.

Answer (score 0):

Do you can use this line to persist the information at Redis, the unique thing that you need to change is to replace the **"** to **'** in your JSON content.

> redisClient.set(Arrays.asList("employee", str ));